# How to change Chrome Extension icon for only active tab with popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a simple chrome extension that can check HTML tags for the current active tab.

When extension icon is clicked, it shows `default popup page(popup.html)`

It will change the extension icon depending on results and shows the results on the popup page.

I'm using `chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: imgSrc})` code to change the icon of extension.

But that problem is that, this code change extension icon on all of another tab.

I wanna change it on only the currently active tab that was clicked extension icon.

I know that I should get the current tab id to change the ext icon for the currently active tab.

For this code `chrome.browserAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: imgSrc})`

But no idea how to get current active tab id on `popup.js`, not `background.js`

Can somebody help me?

here are my files

**manifest.json** that declares `default_popup`

```
{
    "name": "Tag Checker for ChromeExtension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Tag Checker for ChromeExtension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/browserAction/best.png",
            "32": "images/browserAction/normal.png",
            "48": "images/browserAction/bad.png",
            "128": "images/browserAction/abnormal.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tag Checker</title>
    <script src="/js/popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="results"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: '/js/injection.js'});
```

**injection.js**

```
//checking tag codes will be implemented here

var imgSrc = 'images/browserAction/48.png';
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: imgSrc});

(function() {
  document.querySelector('#results').innerText = 'DONE';
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content scripts can't do it.
Move the two lines (imgSrc and setIcon) to popup.js and [specify tabId](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon).

popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: 'images/browserAction/48.png'});
});
```